# Order of promotion of Sanhedrin judges

Tags: sanhedrin

There were three [Sanhedrins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanhedrin) on the Temple Mt: - **The Great**: 71 members and 3 lines of 23 students for filling in or replacing the judges (see [Sanhedrin 37a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.37a.1?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=he)) and - **Two Lesser**: 23 members each, with lines of interns.

There were (theoretically) also 12 Lesser Sanhedrins of the tribes, scattered in Eretz Israel.

The Misha (ibid) states: "*כל אחד ואחד מכיר את מקומו*" - "*each one is aware of his rank*". So seemingly, there was a clear way of promotion for the judges.

What was the order of promotion of a Chacham from the lowest to the highest Sanhedrin? And specifically:

- How do the Lesser Sanhedrins (tribal and on the Temple Mt.) compare? As both are appointed by the Great Sanhedrin.
- Who scores better - a judge on a Lesser Sanhedrin or the 69 interns in the Great Sanhedrin?